# Horizontal Database Partitioning SQL Server 2008 in ASP.net application

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am currently working a project that requires users to be able to view an activity log of all actions that happen on the system. This ASP project is essentially a project tracker that contains tasks within each project. The actions include any additions, deletions, modifications, comments, etc. made to any project or task within a project.

We had an idea of splitting the log table by day. This will help split the actions up made to individual projects given each day which in turn will help display the log data to the user in a very usable way. Doing some research, horizontal partitioning seems to be the best way of achieving this. The reasoning is that each project on any given day could accumulate 100+ actions which in its lifecycle can accumulate upwards of a couple thousand actions until the project is finished. So splitting these actions by day would help in terms of data retrieval efficiency.

If there is a better way of splitting the data up like this aside from partitioning, please let me know. But based on the needs, I believe this is the route we need to take.

However, if this does seem like the best route, trying to figure out how to implement horizontal partitioning to this table is the problem. I have no clue how to go about starting to do so. Most resources I am finding seems to be splitting the table into separate individual files on a file server somewhere. I was seeing if there was a way of dynamically creating these partition tables?

Comment: Just use an index. No need to partition over this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Please excuse my ignorance. But could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I concur with  @JoelCoehoorn . Your description of the scenario does not substantiate the effort involved in splitting the data (Horizontally or otherwise). If your schema is set up well you should be able easily provide the users with any subset of the data which is useful with relatively great performance efficiency (Time/memory)

Comment: If you are the one tasked with setting up the schema/tables make sure they are indexed properly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql